# ORM: Pattern for filtering a lazy collection on an entity

Tags: hibernate, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm posting this question as language and framework agnostic since I think it may be general to ORM Frameworks.

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me if there is a design pattern for the following use case:

**The Use Case**

The system is a Model-View-Controller web application running with an ORM Framework.

There are two entities in play `Poll` and `Vote`.

One `Poll` has a `one-to-many` relationship with `Vote` and votes are in a collection which is *Lazy Loaded*.

Each user in the system can only vote on a poll once.

For the sake of user experience it would be nice for the `View` to adapt by showing controls only for polls on which the current user has not yet voted therefore `Poll` has a method (in pseudocode):

```
public boolean hasVoteFor(user) {
    for each vote
        if vote.user == user
            return true

    return false
}
```

So that when the `View` is passed a `Poll` by the `Controller` it can render the correct controls by doing an `if poll.hasVoteFor(user)`.

**The Problem**

The problem with the above method is that, since the collection is Lazy Loaded, iterating over it could become very memory & db intensive.

Using SQL/DQL/SQL you can obviously use the database to directly query the `Poll` entities on which a user has voted, however any such query should occur in a repository which I'm assuming that the `View` should not have access to.

**Solutions?**

So I'm wondering if there is a design pattern to solve this.

- Should the `Controller` have a method such as `hasVoteFor(poll, user)`? This is problematic if the view renders multiple polls. (A query with many criteria for each poll would be faster rather than doing many selects as the `View` iterates `Poll`s that it is given.)
- Should the `Controller` use a repository to query all the `Poll`s that a user has voted on up front and pass it to the `View` along with the `Poll` (or array of `Poll`). This kind of breaks the neat abstraction of a `Poll` having a `hasVoteFor` method - isn't ORM supposed to let you only think about your objects? ;)
- Some other solution commonly used in practice that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ORM is just a tool to help you with your database. But the database is still the best tool you have to efficiently query for the data you want to display. And using an ORM without understanding and caring about the database and the queries that are generated is a recipe for disaster.

Your second solution is better than the first one, but it's still not as logical and efficient as it could be.

Instead of querying for the poll or polls to display, and then querying for the polls that a user has voted on, and passing these two collections to the view, the controller could execute a query which returns a list of PollWithVoteFlag instances, containing each poll data, along with a flag indicating if the poll has been voted on by the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sounds good to me - with regards to how the ORM should function I knew I was missing something as I could see what the performance impact would have been by just caring about my objects instead of using some kind of query language. The use of the flagged helper object sounds good also, keeps it together and prevents the view from having to compare two collections of data to figure out what is going on.